# Flutter: Do I need to cache widget in onGenerateRoute

Tags: routes, flutter

In `onGenerateRoute` method in `MaterialApp`, it looks wasteful to create Widgets every time, route is changed and Widget will also lose context. Should these widgets `new Desktop(sugar)` be cached and reuse?

```
class AppComponentState extends State<AppComponent> implements SugarBuilder {
  Sugar sugar;

  _getRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final List<String> path = settings.name.split('/');
    if (path[0] != '') return null;
    if (path[1] == 'sugar') {
      if (sugar == null) {
        return Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
      } else {
        if (path[2] == 'module') {
          return new ModulePage(sugar); // need to cache?
        } else {
          return new Desktop(sugar); // need to cache?
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
       ...
       onGenerateRoute: _getRoute,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704251/should-flutter-widgets-be-created-in-the-class-or-in-the-build-function

Comment: Thx. It looks like directly changing state is better then dynamic route.

Comment: It always depends. You can use both approaches. But I haven't yet seen any performance issues because of creating Widgets.

Comment: The trick seems to be [Key](https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/#keys). By giving same key, flutter will not rebuild it, even though `new` widget is given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating new Widget objects should generally be cheap. Flutter's widget framework will take care of updating the render tree when your widgets produce a different render objects. If you have a lot of global state for your app, you can store it in model objects and then pass them to the widgets as needed.

Comment: I see. Creating `new` widget should be cheap if `build` method is never called due to same key. So, it is need to keep the same key and create widget always. It is simpler to implement.